# route show not defined

Tags: laravel, routes

Good afternoon friends, I am developing a quotation system with a module for roles and permits, I find myself working with the shinobi package of the caffeinated provider, I defined the default routes, however it generates an `undefined route error` with the show a route despite being defined in the `web.php` file. Perform the `php artisan route: list` command and it doesn't show me the show route or for quotes, users or roles.

```
Route::post('admin/quotations/store','QuotationController@store')->name('quotations.store')
->middleware('can:quotations.create');

Route::get('admin/quotations','QuotationController@index')->name('quotations.index')
->middleware('can:quotations.index');

Route::get('admin/quotations/create','QuotationController@create')->name('quotations.create')
->middleware('can:quotations.create');

Route::put('admin/quotations/{quotation}','QuotationController@update')->name('quotations.update')
->middleware('can:quotations.edit');

Route::get('admin/quotations/{quotation}','QuotationController@show')->name('quotations.show')
->middleware('can:quotations.show');

Route::delete('admin/quotations/{quotation}','QuotationController@destroy')->name('quotations.destroy')
->middleware('can:quotations.destroy');

Route::get('admin/quotations/{quotation}','QuotationController@edit')->name('quotations.edit')
->middleware('can:quotations.edit');
```

```
<div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                Cotizaciones
                    @can('quotations.create')
                        <a href="{{route ('quotations.create')}}" class="btn btn-success float-right">Crear</a>
                    @endcan
            </div>  
            <div class="card-body">
              <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                    <thead class="table table-primary">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Codigo</th>
                            <th>Cliente</th>
                            <th>Fecha</th>
                            <th>Detalle</th>
                            <th colspan="3">&nbsp;</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tbody>
                            @foreach ($quotations as $quotation)
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{$quotation->id}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$quotation->client->name}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$quotation->created_at}}</td>
                                    <td>
                                          @can('quotations.show')
                                            <a href="{{route ('quotations.show,$quotation->id')}}" class="btn btn-success float-right">Crear</a>
                                        @endcan
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *edit* and *show* routes have the same URI that is the `admin/quotations/{quotation}` part, hence only the last one (edit) is shown. Try making the URIs distinct. That should solve the error.

Comment: Thank you very much friend, with that answer, solve the error, sorry if my English is not very good I am using a translator